# Making a Debug class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, debugging, flash-builder

I saw in some projects that ppl has their own "Debug class".

So, instead of typing: trace("look at this!") you type Debug.trace("look at this!").

The only advantaje I saw was that you can disable every single trace call with a single parameter in the Debug class.. but, thats all.

My question is, what advantages can I obtain if I use a Debug class in AS3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually don't use my debug class that way. I have a logging framework for that, that's what logging is for. My Debug class has things like

```
// I usually use these for debugging and it avoids the need of an 
// additional import.
function whatIs( obj:* ):String{ return getQualifiedClassName( obj )}
function describe( obj:* ):XML{ return describeType( obj ); }
```

I also have a getLines method -- it returns long Strings so that I can easily look at the logging traces and see specific points.

But the most important one:

```
function getStack():String {
    try
    {
        throw new Error( "Someone set us up the bomb!" );
    }
    catch( e:Error )
    {
         return e.getStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I even have a wrapper around getStack which returns the class and method which was most recently called before the method which called getStack().

Comment: It's also superb for having trace/debug statements in the release player. As they all go through your Debug class, you can store them, then display them in an "output" TextField. So if something goes wrong in your release version, you still have debug info

Comment: Oh, and this one time, in AS2, I built a command line in AS2 -- I had a debugger without needing to use the debug class.

Answer (score 1):

A debug class lets you do different levels (notice, warning, error, critical, apocalypse, etc).  As you mentioned, you can disable in a single place.  You can timestamp messages.  You can send output to different places, which can be super handy for debugging a live application or debugging something that happens infrequently.  You can also have some logic to detect the argument types and do different things with the debug info.

Comment: +1 on "You can send output to different places."  @Artemix, how do you know that the only thing Debug.trace does is call trace()?  Maybe it's using a localConnection or an externalInterface as well, and marshalling output to a custom AIR application or sending the data to a server.  The fact that the developers rolled a trace() call into the mix could just be a convenience for ctrl+Enter style local testing, but the real gold could be the potential for logging outside the flash output console.

Comment: In this case, it was only used for that purpose, but I think there was a method called "track" or soemthing like that.